# Automating Gmail with Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, gmail

i want to use selenium to click on a specific button !
the send button on gmail, the standard version and not the basic html version
i tried

```
<tr>
    <td>selectFrame</td>
    <td>c16nfgbb415qzj</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//div[@id=':v9']/b</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

didnot work

give me python code please and not html

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Django, Python or even PHP?  Selenium is a client-side technology scripted using, well, tables or an IDE, and you're trying to scrape gmail, which doesn't use any of those technologies.

Comment: I have retagged and retitled this question to hopefully attract *useful* attention.

Answer (score 1):

You can't record a script in Selenium and play it back using standard Google Mail.  Most of the HTML names/IDs/classes in standard Google Mail are unpredictable.

You'd have to use xpath-based targets with indices e.g. //div[2]/div/div[3].  This has a high-dependency on the structure of the HTML being served by Google Mail.  As soon as it changes, you'll need to modify your script.

The basic HTML version is predictable enough to just record and replay a script.  You didn't say why you don't want to use that.